# Como llenar un combo box de jsp desde un servlet utilizando jstl

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl

La idea es llenar un combobox en jsp desde un servlet, (es un ArrayList) utilizando *jstl*, lo que he conseguido hasta ahora es que solo aparezca el combo vacío.

Cree un método que llena una lista en el servlet y con forward lo redirijo al jsp en cuestión, pero no se que me falte o que pueda estar pasando.

Lo único que quiero es que en **`index.jsp`** me aparezca ese combo lleno listo para que el usuario seleccione una opción.

Imagino que es fácil pero no logro hacerlo, ¿Alguien me podría orientar?

Tengo esto en **`index.jsp`**:

```
<label for="cars">Elige uno: </label>
    <select id="cars" name="selectAutos">
<c:forEach var="vehi" items="${listaA}">
    <option value="${vehi.marca}"></option>
</c:forEach>    
    </select>
```

Y esto en mi servlet:

```
public ListaController(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Auto> listaAuto = llenaLista();
    request.setAttribute("listaA", listaAuto);
        
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //String llenarSelect = request.getParameter("selectAutos");
    List<Auto> listaAuto = llenaLista();
    request.setAttribute("listaA", listaAuto);
        
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Como no estaba usando un formulario no sabia su utilizar el método *doGet* o el constructor del servlet así que utilice ambos pero aun así tengo el error, les agradezco mucho.